# Annotation to only get Date from DateTime

Tags: c#, json, .net

My model class is as follows:

```
public class Person {

    [JsonPropertyName("dob")]
    public DateTime? DOB{ get; set; }

}
```

Above accepts a date time of '2024-03-26T00:00:00'. However, I need the above `DOB` to only capture the date '2024-03-26'. How can I do this by using an annotation only. I don't want to use a converter here.

C# doesn't have a Date property, so how can I only have the date component saved in `DOB` here.

Note: I'm using dotnet 7

Comment: Do you use AutoMapper?

Comment: unfortunately no.

Comment: C# has `DateOnly` as of .Net 6

Comment: you should use `DateOnly` it is  the perfect use for it here

Answer (score 3):

> C# doesn't have a Date property

[DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-8.0) struct, which is supported by `System.Text.Json` in .NET 7 ([usage here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/how-to-use-dateonly-timeonly))